# Replace 10000 elements

Tags: r, subset, gsub, lapply

Suppose there is an object of a million numbers: c(1:1000000).
A 10000-element subset of these c(78,460,...,999390,999612) is ideally replaced by the numbers c(1:10000).

```
total<-c(1:1000000)
out<-c(78,460,...,999390,999612)
in<-c(1:10000)
# to reach output:
total<-c(1:77,1,79:459,2,461:...etc)
```

I could create a hugely long logical with `total==78|total==460|total==...|etc`, but that would takes ages to run. My `gsub`, `subset`, and `lapply` attempts have not brought success. Does anyone have a good solution?

Thank you in advance!!

Red

Comment: just use indexing `total[out] <- inn` dont use `in` as a variable name: see `?Reserved` for other reserved names that you should avoid using

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be the correct method, although unfortunately I run into:  Reached total allocation of 8065Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: `total[out] <- inn` should not allocate any new memory -- where are you getting the total allocation error?